# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I am getting this problem. Can anyone help me?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(DriverService.java:456)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:356)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:160)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:492)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at jashan/jashan.class1.main(class1.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Guava to your class path.

if you use maven, you can add the dependency by adding the following lines to your pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can  download it [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/32.1.2-jre/guava-32.1.2-jre.jar)  and add it manually to your classpath

Comment: that's "if" they use maven